# What is this confusing expression "a == b ? value1 : value2"?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am new to learning C# and Silverlight and have been given some application files by my employer to start learning. I am able to understand most of the logic, methods and syntax used in C# but there is one line which is very confusing to me. I dont have access to my seniors right now to ask them so the logic behind it so I thought I will ask here.

Take a look at this:

In a .xaml.cs file:

```
List<object> lst = new List<object>();
lst.Add(GP.mpl.A);
lst.Add(GP.mpl.B);
lst.Add(GP.mpl.C);
lst.Add(GP.mpl.StnNo);
```

In a different .cs file:

```
public int StnNo = Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString() == string.Empty ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString()));
```

I understand that StnNo is being received from lst[3] and converted to Integer through

```
Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString()
```

But I dont understand this part:

```
== string.Empty ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString())
```

Could you tell me what's going on there? I have done multiple searches on google but didn't find anything related. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `[condition] ? [true part] : [false part]` is equal to `if ([condition]) { [true part] } else { [false part] }`

Comment: [Conditional Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Comment: Would it kill you to try and format code correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` is a ternary operator.

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

- [?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

So in you example,

```
public int StnNo = Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString() == string.Empty ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString()));
```

is equal to

```
public int StnNo;
if (lst[3].ToString() == string.Empty)
{
    StnNo = 0;
}
else
{
    StnNo = Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the *conditional*, sometimes referred to as *ternary*, operator.

It takes the form *boolean expression ? true value : false value.*

In C#, the true value and false value must be of the same type, or one must be implicitly convertible to the other (but not both). Otherwise, you must legally and explicitly cast one or both to a common type.

In your code, you have

```
int StnNo = Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString() == string.Empty ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString()));
```

it is producing the functional equivalent of

```
int temp;
if (lst[3].ToString() == string.Empty)
    temp= 0;
else 
    temp = Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString());

int StnNo = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
```

You can see the outer `Convert.ToInt32` in your code is actually redundant and can be eliminated.

```
int StnNo = lst[3].ToString() == string.Empty ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a very poorly written way of saying "if `lst[3]` is empty, then use `0`, otherwise parse `lst[3]`" - because as your question illustrates, it's harder to tell what exactly the original developer intended.

To make it more clear, let's dissect it.

- `lst[3].ToString() == string.Empty` means "does the `lst[3]` evaluate to an empty string?"
- `? X : Y` means "if so, `X`, otherwise `Y`.

  - `0` a constant value
  - `Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString())` parses the value as an `lst[3]` integer.
- Finally the whole expression is passed into another `Convert.ToInt32`, but this is entirely unnecessary because the result of the conditional expression is always an `int`.

Since you don't have to call `Convert.ToInt32` twice, a better way of writing this would be:

```
public int StnNo = 
    (lst[3].ToString() == string.Empty 
    ? 0 
    : Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString()));
```

An even better way of writing this would be:

```
int StnNo; 
int.TryParse(lst[3], out StnNo);
```

It's more lines of code, but it's a lot easier to read.

Comment: @Corak bad in the sense of being illegible. It's also redundant in calling `ToString()` and `Convert.ToInt32` twice when it's really not needed.

Comment: Well, that depends on what you're used to. Someone working with `IDisposable` objects who only ever uses `try ... finally` might not understand the "weird" `using (...)`. Calling `Convert.ToInt32` twice is of course unnecessary. And `Int32.TryParse` should be used more often anyways (except when you *do* want to throw an error). But your post implies that `?:` is "bad" in and of itself. Which is not true. At most, it's not that well known.

Comment: @Corak `?:`, like most other elements of syntax, is only *bad* when obscures the developers' intent. I've tried to clarify the wording a bit in my answer.

Comment: I can agree with this wording. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

`== string.Empty ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(lst[3].ToString())` is to check that if `lst[3]` does not contain any value, then 0 will be assigned to `StnNo`.